# How can I convert an action in terms of differential forms to tensors?

Tags: action, tensor-calculus

I have an action of a gravitational theory wich is in terms of differential forms. Now, I need to transform this action (including wedge product and exterior derivative of tetrad and metric ) to an action in terms of tensors.i mean converting it into component notation.
How can I do this calculation?
Or can anyone introduce me a book or paper in this way?

for example the action of a theory is

$S = \int g_{ij}(x) \partial_{\mu} X^i \, \partial^{\mu}X^j$

but it is possible to write this action as

$\bar{\delta}_XS[X,\gamma]=-\int_\Sigma \eta_{\mu \nu} \bar{\delta}X^{\mu}\wedge d \star_\gamma d X^\nu=0$

Now I want to know that how the first form can be achieved from the second one.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Differential forms _are_ tensors. Do you mean converting it into component notation?

Comment: @knzhou yes, exactly. I should edit the question then.

Comment: If you know what a differential form is you should have no trouble doing this - it's tedious to write out every form in its components, but it's unclear where exactly you run into conceptual trouble. Can you be more precise what's unclear to you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind for example the action of a theory is S = \int g_{ij}(x) \partial_{\mu} X^i \, \partial^{\mu}X^j but it is possible to write this action as \bar{\delta}_XS[X,\gamma]=-\int_\Sigma \eta_{\mu \nu} \bar{\delta}X^{\mu}\wedge d \star_\gamma d X^\nu=0 . Now i want to know that how the first form can be achieved  from the second one.

Comment: @physicsportal You should include that particular example in the body of your question, and use $ signs to convert the text into LaTeX.