# Converting gravity action from differential forms to tensor component

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, action

I deal with this action but i really do not know how differential forms can be expressed in terms of tensor components.

$$
S\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} M_{pl}^2\int_{M}\epsilon_{abcd}\left(e^a\wedge e^{b}\wedge\Omega^{cd}\right)=M_{pl}^2\int_{M}d^4x\, \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\epsilon_{abcd}\,e^{a}_{\mu}\,e^{b}_{\nu}\, R^{cd}_{\rho\sigma}[\omega]
$$

Can anyone help me in this way? 
Or introduce me a book or paper related to my questions?

Comment: Uh... isn’t the right hand side already in components?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370200/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your conventions for the Riemann tensor or curvature two forms, but this should be fine. we have that $$\Omega^{cd} = R^{cd}{}_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$$ in local coordinates (we must be careful really, since the coordinates may not be defined everywhere on the manifold.) Next, the tetrad/vierbein satisfies $e^a = e^a_\mu dx^\mu$. So the left hand side amounts to

$$M_{pl}^2 \int_M \epsilon_{abcd}(e^a_\mu dx^\mu)\wedge (e^b_\nu dx^\nu)\wedge R^{cd}{}_{\rho\sigma}dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma 
$$

The basis 1 forms are the only things that care about the wedge product/exterior product, but the functions that sit in front of them can be moved:

$$M_{pl}^2 \int_M \epsilon_{abcd}(e^a_\mu dx^\mu)\wedge (e^b_\nu dx^\nu)\wedge R^{cd}{}_{\rho\sigma}dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma = M_{pl}^2 \int_M \epsilon_{abcd}e^a_{\mu} e^b_\nu R^{cd}{}_{\rho\sigma}dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu\wedge dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma
$$

Note however, that the $dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu\wedge dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma$ is a permutation of the volume element $d^4x$ provided that no two indices are identical (otherwise it vanishes). Thus $dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu\wedge dx^\rho \wedge dx^\sigma = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} d^4 x$, and hence we have the result.

Comment: @ mkf Great,Thank you very much my dear friend. Would you please introduce me a book or paper about this subject?

Comment: @physicsportal no problemo, so If you want a introduction to the tetrad formalism, you can find information on wiki about the objects: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism, and for the exterior calculus, you could try Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds", Chapter 4 onwards; whilst he restricts to Euclidean space, on every local neighbourhood of a manifold, you can map into Euclidean space, hence why I wrote "coordinates may not be defined everywhere on the manifold". See if it helps, if not, come back to me, and I'll give you some more references

Comment: @mkt thank you very much my dear friend :). I truely apreciate you.